# Iterating through array throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Sorry if the question sound stupid. I am trying to make an labirint solving problem in java(The labirint have # as wall ' 'as walkable place and 'k'as start position and I am trying to iterate through an objects array to find an specific index
I have the sequence of code:

```
 if(checkIfKateCanMoveFurther(mazeMatrix,katePosition)) {
                lastPositionWithUnvisitedNeighbours = changeTheLastPositionWithUnvisitedNeighbours(whitespaces);
            }
```

the changeTheLastPositionWithUnvisitedNeighbours method:

```
 public static int changeTheLastPositionWithUnvisitedNeighbours(MazeElementCoodinate[] whiteSpaces) {
        int index=0;
        for(int i=0;i<whiteSpaces.length;i++){
            if(whiteSpaces[i].getNumberOfPermisiveNeighbours()>2)
                index=i;
        }
        return index;
    }
```

here is how I fill the array:

```
    public static MazeElementCoodinate[] fillWhiteSpacesArray(Character[][] mazeMatrix) {
        int x=0;
        MazeElementCoodinate[] whiteSpacesArray=new MazeElementCoodinate[100];
        for (int i=0;i<mazeMatrix.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<mazeMatrix[i].length;j++) {
                if (mazeMatrix[i][j]=='k'||mazeMatrix[i][j]==' ') {
                    whiteSpacesArray[x]=new MazeElementCoodinate(i,j,calculateNumberOfNeighbours(mazeMatrix,i,j));
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
        return whiteSpacesArray;
    }
```

The  changeTheLastPositionWithUnvisitedNeighbours throw me the error and I don t know why

the Maze Element

```
public class MazeElementCoordinate {
    private int xCoordinate;
    private int yCoordinate;
    private int numberOfPermisiveNeighbours;//a permiseive neighbour allow me to move into his position;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure your data structure is sound. Why not using an array of arrays with each element containing either k, space or #. Then you take it from there.

Comment: When you create the white spaces array you set it too size 100 but it is not certain that the whole array gets filled with objects judging by your code

Comment: What's the error that you get? You should get a stacktrace which will give you a line number showing where the `NullPointerException` is thrown, which should show you what exactly is `Null`.